# Shaky CSS3 width transition in WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, jquery-animate, css-transitions, packery

I'm working on an animation using [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co). Tiles are aligned in a grid and clicking on one is supposed to enlarge it and dynamically rearrange the tiles accordingly. The resizing is animated using CSS3 transitions. All of this works as expected in IE10 and Firefox, as demonstrated in the following codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ilkmK

The same code in WebKit-based browsers (tested on Windows) produces a frantic wiggle / shaking of the box as it is resized and repositioned.

I already submitted an [issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/107) and the problem seems to be that width and height transitions in WebKit are not optimized. Implementing the same animation using jQuery.animate improved the situation a little bit, but it doesn't get rid of the wiggle. Especially on slower systems it remains very noticable.

For now I'm using the JavaScript version as a slightly better fallbackf or webkit browsers, but it's not optimal. I have no idea where to go from here, so I was hoping Stackoverflow could help me out.

For any hints on how to make this work in Chrome/Safari, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in Chrome on mac and it's working fine, so I can't replicate the problem. However I have a feeling this might be to do with the fact that when webkit browsers load a page they initially generate images with 0 dimensions.

Try putting your jQuery in `$(window).load(function(){` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){`

That would wait for images to load before executing the script.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the problem. It makes no difference whatsoever. Also it appears that the effect is less notable on fast computers.

Comment: OK. In that case I can't help you anymore as I can't replicate the problem.